# After filling HD drive with /dev/zero -> shutdown and error

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, external-hdd

**My intent:**

i wanted to fill my external HDD (1TB) with zeros so i used:

```
dd if=/dev/zero | pv -t -e -r -a -b -s 930000000000 | dd of=/media/usb/clearAll ; rm /media/usb/clearAll ; shutdown -P 00
```

**Explaining the command above:**

After completely filling the HDD with zero I wanted to delete that file and after deleting that file i wanted to shutdown my laptop due the fact that it will take several hours and I need to sleep as well. Yeah i know, i did forget to unmount the external HDD before shutting down.

pv is just to monitor to progress of the file transfers.

**The problem:**

Everything worked fine for 2minutes then ubuntu was shutting down normally! After 2 minutes? Where just about 6-7GB where occupied.

So i did start my laptop again to take a closer look at the syslog getting following:

```
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [27033.291030] init: tty4 main process (1006) killed by TERM signal
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [27033.291240] init: tty5 main process (1010) killed by TERM signal
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [27033.291383] init: tty2 main process (1016) killed by TERM signal
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [27033.291525] init: tty3 main process (1017) killed by TERM signal
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [27033.291672] init: tty6 main process (1020) killed by TERM signal
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [27033.313817] init: irqbalance main process (1081) killed by TERM signal
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [27033.313957] init: cron main process (1083) killed by TERM signal
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [27033.314282] init: tty1 main process (1195) killed by TERM signal
Mar 15 20:04:18 Mikes-Laptop rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="747" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

and also

```
Mar 15 20:06:36 Mikes-Laptop kernel: [   11.319099] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

but i'm not sure if it is corresponding to the unexpected shutdown.

**The question:**

So can someone tell me what i did wrong? I thought every command after ; will be execute after the preceding one has finished.

**Specs:**

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Seagate 1TB external HDD MSDOS FAT32 one Partition occupying the whole drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected a error, if the filesystem is formatted in FAT32 or a similar file system that supports a maximum of 4GB per file and you tried to make a 1TB file on the HDD, the most probable fail is that when the file reached 4GB, the program stopped and the computer halted.

The correct command would be:

```
dd if=/dev/zero | pv -t -e -r -a -b -s 930000000000 | dd of="/dev/sdX"; shutdown -P 00
```

where the correct path may be `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`. You can find that letter in the "Disks" program of Ubuntu.

**Warning: ENSURE THAT YOU ENTER THE CORRECT DEVICE, IT MAY PRODUCE A BIG DATA LOSS**

Comment: Can i look that up in a specified log? Also, you mean my internal HDD was faulty and because of that mounted as read only forcing the system to reboot? Was it harmful?

Comment: You can look in `/var/log/syslog` for disk error messages. I'm not sure of your disk health, I can't say something absolute. I not said that the disk forced the system to reboot, I said that when the hdd seemed to fail, `dd` stopped and executed the last command.

Comment: Sorry, I failed, I don't read well your command. I edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah, i can't find anything with disk and error in syslog using: sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep disk?

Comment: Ah ok, but i mounted the external HDD to /media/usb! Is this not allowed using data description (dd) ?

Comment: No, you need to fill with zeros **the device** and not *a file*

Comment: Ok in fact with your command in you answere i'm creating a big file with zeros why i'm not allowed to write that to the directory where the device is mounted? where's the difference?

Comment: Completely wrong. You need to fill *the device* with zeros, and the device is represented in linux by a file in `/dev/`. If do you fill *the partition* there are more chances to recover data of it by another person. And if the filesystem is FAT32, you can't fill the partition because the limit per file is 4GB and the disk haves 1TB.

Comment: Ah ok now i understand! Yes this sounds logical. So dd aborted when the file reached the maximum file size of 4GB (regarding to FAT32). And after that i executed the shutdown command. So i will do two things to prevent this. First i will use NTFS File-System and i will do `&&` instead of `;` only executing the shutdown if everything else worked fine. Thank you Helios i will try, if it works i will accept your answere!

Comment: One last question, should i go for the partition which occupies the whole disk eg. `sdb1` or just `sdb` ?

Comment: If you will only use your HDD with Linux, I'll suggest you to format as EXT4, and if you will not give/sell the HDD to anybody, I think that the zero-fill is a waste of time, because you may not need to make unrecoverable your old data. If you will use your HDD with Windows and Linux, the best choice may be NTFS (or FAT32 if you will not need to store big files). And about the last question: Is preferable to fill the whole disk (`sdb`), `sdb1` is the first partition of `sdb`.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to achieve it.